# String.replaceAll single backslashes with double backslashes

Tags: java, escaping, backslash, replaceall

I'm trying to convert the `String`  `\something\` into the `String` `\\something\\` using `replaceAll`, but I keep getting all kinds of errors. I thought this was the solution:

```
theString.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\");
```

But this gives the below exception:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

The [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) interprets the argument as a [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). The `\` is an escape character in **both** `String` and `regex`. You need to double-escape it for regex:

```
string.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

But you don't necessarily need regex for this, simply because you want an exact character-by-character replacement and you don't need patterns here. So [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) should suffice:

```
string.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

---

**Update**: as per the comments, you appear to want to use the string in JavaScript context. You'd perhaps better use [`StringEscapeUtils#escapeEcmaScript()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeEcmaScript(java.lang.String)) instead to cover more characters.

Comment: Actually, it is used in a JavaScript AST that should be converted back to source. Your solution works. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use `String#replaceAll()` anyway, you can quote the replacement string with [Matcher#quoteReplacement()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)): `theString.replaceAll("\\", Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"));`

Comment: Matcher.quoteReplacement( ... ) is a good way! Please see Pshemo's answer!

Answer (score 21):

TLDR: use `theString = theString.replace("\\", "\\\\");` instead.

---

#### Problem

`replaceAll(target, replacement)` uses regular expression (regex) syntax for `target` and partially for `replacement`.

Problem is that `\` is special character in regex (it can be used like `\d` to represents digit) and in String literal (it can be used like `"\n"` to represent line separator or `\"` to escape double quote symbol which normally would represent end of string literal).

In both these cases to create `\` symbol we can *escape* it (make it literal instead of special character) by placing additional `\` before it (like we escape `"` in string literals via `\"`).

So to `target` regex representing `\` symbol will need to hold `\\`, and string literal representing such text will need to look like `"\\\\"`.

So we escaped `\` twice:

- once in regex `\\`
- once in String literal `"\\\\"` (each `\` is represented as `"\\"`).

In case of `replacement` `\` is also special there. It allows us to escape other special character `$` which via `$x` notation, allows us to use portion of data matched by regex and held by capturing group indexed as `x`, like `"012".replaceAll("(\\d)", "$1$1")` will match each digit, place it in capturing group 1 and `$1$1` will replace it with its two copies (it will duplicate it) resulting in `"001122"`.

So again, to let `replacement` represent `\` literal we need to escape it with additional `\` which means that:

- replacement must hold two backslash characters `\\`
- and String literal which represents `\\` looks like `"\\\\"`

BUT since we want `replacement` to hold *two* backslashes we will need `"\\\\\\\\"` (each `\` represented by one `"\\\\"`).

So version with `replaceAll` can look like

```
replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

#### Easier way with `replaceAll`

To make out life easier Java provides tools to automatically escape text into `target` and `replacement` parts. So now we can focus only on strings, and forget about regex syntax:

```
replaceAll(Pattern.quote(target), Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement))
```

which in our case can look like

```
replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\"))
```

#### Even better: use `replace`

If we don't really need regex syntax support lets not involve `replaceAll` at all. Instead lets use `replace`. Both methods will replace ***all*** `target`s, but `replace` doesn't involve regex syntax. So you could simply write

```
theString = theString.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

Answer (score 14):

To avoid this sort of trouble, you can use `replace` (which takes a plain string) instead of `replaceAll` (which takes a regular expression). You will still need to escape backslashes, but not in the wild ways required with regular expressions.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to escape the (escaped) backslash in the first argument as it is a regular expression. Replacement (2nd argument - see [Matcher#replaceAll(String)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))) also has it's special meaning of backslashes, so you'll have to replace those to:

```
theString.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes... by the time the regex compiler sees the pattern you've given it, it sees only a single backslash (since Java's lexer has turned the double backwhack into a single one). You need to replace `"\\\\"` with `"\\\\"`, believe it or not! Java really needs a good raw string syntax.