# Why String.replaceAll() don't work on this String?

Tags: java, regex, string

```
    //This source is a line read from a file 
    String src = "23570006,music,**,wu(),1,exam,\"Monday9,10(H2-301)\",1-10,score,";

    //This sohuld be from a matcher.group() when Pattern.compile("\".*?\"")
    String group = "\"Monday9,10(H2-301)\"";

    src = src.replaceAll("\"", "");
    group = group.replaceAll("\"", "");

    String replacement = group.replaceAll(",", "#@");
    System.out.println(src.contains(group));
    src = src.replaceAll(group, replacement);
    System.out.println(group);
    System.out.println(replacement);
    System.out.println(src);
```

I'm  trying to replace the `","` between `\"s` so I can use `String.split()` latter.

But the above just not working , the result is:

```
true  
Monday9,10(H2-301)  
Monday9#@10(H2-301)  
23570006,music,**,wu(),1,exam,Monday9,10(H2-301),1-10,score,
```

but when I change the src string to

```
 String src = "123\"9,10\"123";  
 String group = "\"9,10\"";
```

It works well

```
true  
9,10  
9#@10  
1239#@10123
```

What's the matter with the string???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(` and `)` are regex metacharacter; they need to be escaped if you want to match it literally.

```
String group = "\"Monday9,10\\(H2-301\\)\"";
                            ^        ^
```

The reason why you need two slashes is that because `\` in a string literal is itself an escape character, so `"\\"` is a string of length 1 containing a slash.