# How do I replace all asterisks?

Tags: java, regex

In Java, I want to replace all `*` characters with `\*`.

Example:
Text: `select * from blah`

Result: `select \\* from blah`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "select * from blah";
    test = test.replaceAll("*", "\\*");
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

This does not work, nor does adding a escape backslash.

Comment: Why is this tagged regex?  You are not using any regular expressions...

Comment: `replaceAll` uses regular expressions thus the first argument is the regular expression `*`. `*` is a regular expression *metacharacter* and has a special meaning. You should read a regular expression tutorial, for example: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html.

Comment: @Ed Swangren He is, _replaceAll_ takes regex string as first parameter

Comment: @Richard: and there's the clue...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 24):

I figured it out

```
    String test = "select * from blah *asdf";
    test = test.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\*");
    System.out.println(test);
```

Comment: test = test.replaceAll(@"\*", @"\\*"); I hate \\ personally, and prefer to use string literals.

Comment: @WernerCD: I've never seen that. What syntax is that?

Comment: @WernerCD: Looks like C# not Java to me.

Comment: If you've discovered your own solution, you should accept this as the answer to your question.

Comment: @JoshD — SO forces you to wait (three days, IIRC) before accepting your own answer.

Comment: @WernerCD: `replaceAll()` is Java, but `@""` is a C# verbatim string literal--Java has nothing like them.

Comment: Ahh... Sorry... thought it was C#. My bad :) Yeah... that's C#, I'm surprised Java has nothing like it... It's late and my brain is mush.

Comment: This works, but it is overkill. There's no need to use regex for simple String replacement.

Answer (score 12):

You don't need any regex functionality for this, so you should use the non-regex version [String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29):

```
String test = "select * from blah *asdf";
test = test.replace("*", "\\*");
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 7):

For those of you keeping score at home, and since understanding the answer may be helpful to someone else...

```
String test = "select * from blah *asdf";
test = test.replaceAll("\\*", "\\\\*");
System.out.println(test);
```

works because you must escape the special character `*` in order to make the regular expression happy. However, `\` is a special character in a Java string, so when building this regex in Java, you must also escape the `\`, hence `\\*`.

This frequently leads to what amounts to double-escapes when putting together regexes in Java strings.