# Replace substring (replaceAll) workaround

Tags: java, string, substring, replaceall

I'm trying to replace a substring that contains the char "$". I'd be glad to hear why it didnt works that way, and how it would work.

Thanks,
user_unknown

```
public class replaceall {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s1= "$foo - bar - bla";
        System.out.println("Original string:\n"+s1);
        String s2 = s1.replaceAll("bar", "this works");
        System.out.println("new String:\n"+s2);
        String s3 = s2.replaceAll("$foo", "damn");
        System.out.println("new String:\n"+s3);
    }

}
```

Comment: And what does this print out? `$foo - this works - bla`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Java's `.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) implicitly uses Regex to replace. That means, `$foo` is interpreted as a regex pattern, and `$` is special in regex (meaning "end of string").

You need to escape the `$` as

```
String s3 = s2.replaceAll("\\$foo", "damn");
```

if the target a variable, use `Pattern.quote` to escape all special characters on Java ≥1.5, and if the replacement is also a variable, use `Matcher.quoteReplacement`.

```
String s3 = s2.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("$foo"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("damn"));
```

On Java ≥1.5, you could [use `.replace` instead](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
String s3 = s2.replace("$foo", "damn");
```

Result: http://www.ideone.com/Jm2c4

Comment: Very good answer, but IMHO you are solving the wrong problem.

Comment: Also note that replacement string for `replaceAll()` may need escaping too (with `Pattern.quoteReplacement()`).

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need Regex functionality, don't use the regex version.

Use `String.replace(str, str)` instead:

```
String s = "$$$";
String rep = s.replace("$", "€");
System.out.println(rep);
// Output: €€€
```

**Reference:**

- [String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [String.replaceAll(String, String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: +1 - I'd accepted this answer. replaceAll is for replacing matches of a pattern, replace for char sequence substitution (which is exactly what we want here)

Answer (score 5):

IIRC, replaceAll take a regex : Try to escape the $, this way :

```
String s3 = s2.replaceAll("\\$foo", "damn");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String safeReplaceAll(String orig, String target, String replacement) {
    replacement = replacement.replace("$", "\\$");
    return orig.replaceAll(target, replacement);
}
```