# Why does this Java String.replaceAll() code not work?

Tags: java, string, api, replaceall

I have used string.replaceAll() in Java before with no trouble, but I am stumped on this one. I thought it would simply just work since there are no "/" or "$" characters. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
String testString = "__constant float* windowArray";
String result = testString.replaceAll("__constant float* windowArray", "__global float* windowArray");
```

The variable result ends up looking the same as testString. I don't understand why there is no change, please help.

Comment: Wow.  The more I learn about Java the more I like C#.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument passed to replaceAll is still treated as a regular expression. The `*` character is a special character meaning, roughly, the previous thing in the string (here: `t`), can be there 0 or more times. What you want to do is escape the `*` for the regular expression. Your first argument should look more like:

```
"__constant float\\* windowArray"
```

The second argument is, at least for your purposes, still just a normal string, so you don't need to escape the `*` there.

```
String result = testString.replaceAll("__constant float\\* windowArray", "__global float* windowArray");
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to escape the * since it is a special character in regular expressions.

So `testString.replaceAll("__constant float\\* windowArray", "__global float\\* windowArray");`

Comment: Or, if manual escaping is not feasible (e.g. when building a pattern at runtime), use `Pattern.quote(String)` and `Matcher.quoteReplacement(String)`.

Answer (score 2):

The ***** is a regex quantifier.  The **replaceAll** method use regex.  To avoid using regular expressions try using the **replace** method instead.

Example:

```
String testString = "__constant float* windowArray";
String replaceString = "__global float* windowArray";
String result = testString.replace(testString.subSequence(0, testString.length()-1), 
            replaceString.subSequence(0, replaceString.length()-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = testString.replaceAll("__constant float windowArray\\\\*", "__global float\\* windowArray");
```