# Code Not Producing Expected Results

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I'm fairly new to Java. I am coding a Symmetric-Key Encryption Program that encrypts a string entered at command line. For some reason, this section is not giving me the results I was looking for:

```
    String[] replaceNum = {
        " 1 ", " 2 ", " 3 ", " 4 ", " 5 ", " 6 ", " 7 ", " 8 ", " 9 ", 
" 10 ", " 11 ", " 12 ", " 13 ", " 14 ", " 15 ", " 16 ", " 17 ", " 18 ", 
" 19 ", " 20 ", " 21 ", " 22 ", " 23 ", " 24  ", " 25 ", " 26 ", " 27 ",
" 28 ", " 29 ", " 30 ", " 31 "};

    String[] replaceChar = {
        " A ", " B ", " C ", " D ", " E ", " F ", " G ", " H ", " I ",
" J ", " K ", " L ", " M ", " N ", " O ", " P ", " Q ", " R ", " S ",
" T ", " U ", " V ", " W ", " X  ", " Y ", " Z ", " . ", " //, ", 
" //! ", " //? ", " _ "};


    message = message.toUpperCase();
    message = message.replaceAll(" ", "_");
    message = " " + message.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ") + " ";

    for (int x=0; x<=30; x++) {
        message = message.replaceAll(replaceChar[x], replaceNum[x]);
    }
```

Basically, I want to replace the characters in the message string with numbers from 1 to 31. When I compile, the output will be something like some# 27 some# 27 some# 27... It worked fine when I used 31 lines of

```
message = message.replaceAll("character", "number");
```

Also, if I include any punctuation, I get an error. Not very familiar with "//", and don't really understand "Regex". Please help!

Comment: Further in the code, when I convert the numbers back to letters using this same method, it works fine; and it is the same code.

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be \\? or \\! because \\ is used to escape special character like ? and ! in regex and treat them like normal character so it would make sense if you were intending it to be \\ instead of //

Comment: `.` (that corresponds to `27` in your code) has a special meaning in regular expressions. It matches any character other than end-of-line.  The nature of your problem is the same as in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109925/why-does-this-java-string-replaceall-code-not-work?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109925/why-does-this-java-string-replaceall-code-not-work?rq=1).

Comment: The code works! Just changed to "\\.", "\\," ... Thank you very much for solving this! @CodyAnderson

Comment: No problem I reposted my comment as an answer if you could take the time to mark it as your answer it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's supposed to be `\\?` or `\\!` because `\\` is used to escape special character like `?` and `!` in regex and treat them like normal character so you want to change it to `\\` instead of `//`