# String.replaceAll without RegEx

Tags: java

I'd like to replace all instances of a substring in a string but `String.replaceAll()` only accepts a pattern. The string that I have came from a previous match. Is it possible to add escapes to the pattern that I have or is there a version of `replaceAll()` in another class which accepts a literal string instead of a pattern?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

Just use [`String.replace(CharSequence,CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) rather than `replaceAll`.

NB: `replace` doesn't just replace the first occurrence, it replaces **all** occurrences, like `replaceAll`.

Comment: This doesn't just replace the first? Weird they called it "replaceAll" instead of "replaceRegex".

Comment: ```System.out.println("hello world, hello life, hello you".replace("hello","hi"));``` returns ```"hi world, hi life, hi you"```.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: Yes, I agree it was very poor naming - it's caused a lot of confusion over time.

Comment: very bad naming of the  methods.  Why do they(sun/oracle) make simple things complicated

Comment: I believe the naming of `replaceAll` (regex method) was to differentiate from `replaceFirst` (regex method), not so much to differentiate from `replace` (non regex method).

Comment: When I try that, why is Android Studio bleating "'replace()' could be replaced with compiled 'java.util.regex.Pattern' construct", as if replace() used a regular expression, when the internal documentation for replace() says "literal target sequence"?

Comment: @Phlip: It may well be that a compiled pattern would be more efficient than using `replace()`. I don't know the details, but that seems entirely plausible. (I would also suggest trying to use dismissive language like "bleating" to describe behavior.)

Answer (score 106):

The method to add escapes is [`Pattern.quote()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)).

```
String replaced = myString.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(matchingStr), replacementStr)
```

But as Jon says you can just use `replace()`.  Despite the fact that it deviates from the `replaceAll` name, it does replace *all* occurrences just like `replaceAll()`.

Comment: Works perfectly if you havea  "$" in your matchingStr for example.

Comment: rather Pattern.compile();
Pattern.quote() brings undesirable results

Comment: @PavloZvarych: `Pattern.compile()` compiles the string as a regular expression, meaning the special characters will be given the special meaning.  That's the complete opposite of what `Pattern.quote()` does, and what the OP was asking for (`quote()` says, "treat the string as a literal").  Maybe you could expand on what "undesirable results" you're talking about.

Comment: @MarkPeters it was something like \\G1\\G for "$1"

Comment: @PavloZvarych: I get `\Q$1\E`, which is exactly what I'd expect.

Comment: @MarkPeters, to be honest I was passing "$aa +" to Pattern.quote() method and was expected that I will get the same String as a result after replaceAll() method call. I just needed the same result at the output. Pattern.compile() as it seems helped. I even don't know what to do with such a "\Q$1\E" String.

Comment: @PavloZvarych: If you're trying to quote the replacement (and not the search pattern), you want to use `Matcher.quoteReplacement("$aa +")`.  `Pattern.compile()` produces a `Pattern`, not a `String`, so it's unclear to me how you are even using it in `replaceAll`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114668/discussion-between-pavlo-zvarych-and-mark-peters).