# Replace all with a string having regex wild chars

Tags: java, regex, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java String.replaceAll without regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316710/java-string-replaceall-without-regex)

I have a string and I need to replace some parts of it.
The replacement text contains regex wild chars though. Example:

```
String target = "Something * to do in ('AAA', 'BBB')";    
String replacement = "Hello";    
String originalText = "ABCDEFHGIJKLMN" + target + "ABCDEFHGIJKLMN";  
System.out.println(originalText.replaceAll(target, replacement));
```

I get:
`ABCDEFHGIJKLMNSomething * to do in ('AAA', 'BBB')ABCDEFHGIJKLMN`

Why doesn't the replacement occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `*`, `(` and `)` are all meta-characters in regular expressions. Hence all of them need to be escaped. It looks like Java has a convenient method for this:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(target)
```

However, the better option might be, to just not use the regex-using `replaceAll` function [but simply `replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316710/java-string-replaceall-without-regex). Then you do not need to escape anything.

Comment: Using `quote` I get: `ABCDEFHGIJKLMN\QHello\EABCDEFHGIJKLMN`. How can I get rid of `Q`?

Comment: @Jim.. No you shouldn't get that. It should work fine. How have you used it?

Comment: I did: `target = Pattern.quote(target);  
target = Pattern.quote(target);  
String replacement = "Hello";    
String originalText = "ABCDEFHGIJKLMN" + target + "ABCDEFHGIJKLMN";  
System.out.println(originalText.replaceAll(target, replacement));`

Comment: @Jim this also puts the escaped target in your initial string. of course you only need to escape it when you use it as a regex. leave `target` as it is, and feed `replaceAll` with the snippet from my answer. or use `replace` anyway.

Comment: because you do this twice `target = Pattern.quote(target);`, do it once and it will work like @m.buettner says.

Answer (score 2):

`String.replaceAll()` takes a regular expression and so it's trying to expand these metacharacters.

One approach is to *escape* these chars (e.g. `\*`).

Another would be to do the replacement yourself by using [String.indexOf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29) and finding the start of the contained string. `indexOf()` doesn't take a regexp but rather a normal string.