# Replace a pattern in a long String. Used replace method in a loop, but every time it will replace the first occurrence

Tags: java

Replace a pattern in a long String. Used replace method in a loop, but every time it will replace the first occurrence.

I want to Iterate and replace all occurrences one by one for example

```
LongString.contains("/ima?pth=") 
LongString=LongString.replace("/ima?pth=", "/ima?pth=**1**");
```

Every time I have to add a new number at the end of the occurrence it can be any value. How to do this in Java?

Answer (score 0):

According to [String.replaceAll without RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4316710/string-replaceall-without-regex) it should replace all... Otherwise you could put in a while loop. I caution this though, as LongString.contains("/ima?pth=") would still be true when it is all replaced. Would be easy to have an infinite loop.

Comment: replace will everytime replace first occurance

Comment: I want to iterate through the string match pattern replace it with  "/ima?pth=**1**"

Comment: String newBody=body.replace("<img src=", "<img src=\"cid:"+n+"");  n is any random number. Everytime it will replace the first occurance of <img src  which i donot want , there  are many <img drc tags to be replaced

Comment: Ah.. I misunderstood the question. I would change your "contains" to include what follows the "<img src=" when it is first blank. Then you can keep a counter in the while(could also do a for loop) and replace with that variable 
   LongString=LongString.replace("/ima?pth=", "/ima?pth=" + varName);

Answer (score 0):

**Use `Matcher` and `Matcher#appendReplacement()`**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class ReplaceAllEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "randomPrefix"
                + "/ima?pth=randomInfix/ima?pth="
                + "/ima?pth=randomInfix/ima?pth="
                ;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/ima\\?pth=");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        int i = 1;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println("input is\n" + input + "\n");
        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "/ima?pth="+"**"+i+"**");
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("output is\n" + sb.toString() + "\n");
    }

}
```

The output of the above program would be:

```
input is
randomPrefix/ima?pth=randomInfix/ima?pth=/ima?pth=randomInfix/ima?pth=

output is
randomPrefix/ima?pth=**1**randomInfix/ima?pth=**2**/ima?pth=**3**randomInfix/ima?pth=**4**
```

**Updated**

Here is another example demonstrating the use of `Matcher#appendReplacement()` -- with OP's new input example.

```
private static void example2() {
    String input = "<img src=\"cid:1\"/>"
    private static void example2() {
        String input = "<img src=\"cid:1\"/>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "</span><div>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "<br /></span></div>"
//              + "<div>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "<br /></span></div>"
//              + "<div>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "</span><br /><div style=\"display:none;\">"
//              + "</div></div><div>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "<br /></span></div><div>"
                + "<img src=\"/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c\"/>"
//              + "<span style=\"font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';\">"
//              + "<br /></span>"
                + "<img src=\"/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c\"/>"
                + "<img src=\"/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c\"/>"
                ;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<img src=\\\"/XP/image\\?path=09021b5e80061f2c\\\"/>");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
        int i = 2;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        System.out.println("input is\n" + input + "\n");
        while (m.find()) {
            String replacement = String.format("<img src=\"cid: %d\"/>", i);
            m.appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("output is\n" + sb.toString() + "\n");

    }
```

This would be the program output:

```
input is
<img src="cid:1"/><img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/><img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/><img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/>

output is
<img src="cid:1"/><img src="cid: 2"/><img src="cid: 3"/><img src="cid: 4"/>
```

Comment: <img src="cid:1"/><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"></span><div><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"><br /></span></div><div><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"><br /></span></div><div><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"></span><br /><div style="display:none;"></div></div><div><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"><br /></span></div><div><img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/><span style="font-size:14pt;font-family:'Times New Roman';"><br /></span>

Comment: I was able to replace the first occurance of string with <img src="cid:1"/>,

Comment: But how can i replace all the occurances. <img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/>  with  <img src="cid:1"/>   2 , 3 ,4 so on..

Comment: @Jimmy_R -- In your first comment above, there seems to be only one occurrence of `<img src="/XP/image?path=09021b5e80061f2c"/>`. Anyway, if you think my answer is pointing you in the right direction.  Please upvote it and accept it.  I can see if I can post an update to the answer to address your new example.

Comment: leeyuiwah- I did . thanks for the help , Voted up too :) :)

Comment: @Jimmy_R -- I have updated my answer above.  You can take it from there.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) like so:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String longString = "qwe/ima?pth=asdzxc/ima?pth=qweasd/ima?pth=sdf";
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(longString);
    String pattern = "/ima?pth=";
    int index = longString.indexOf(pattern);
    int number = 1;
    while(index >= 0) {
     str.insert(index + pattern.length(), number);
     index = str.indexOf("/ima?pth=", index+1);
     number += 1;
    }
    longString = str.toString();
    System.out.println(longString); //qwe/ima?pth=1asdzxc/ima?pth=2qweasd/ima?pth=3sdf
  }
}
```

You could modify the operations on `number` as desired but in this instance it only goes up by 1.

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FT4O/0)

Answer (score 0):

replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)

Should have you covered