# How do I replace the a portion of the string with special characters

Tags: java, string, replace

I would like to replace a certain portion of the string with `"\\_\\_\\_\\_\\_"`

```
(e.g. String str = "Hello World")
```

If I do `str.replaceAll("World", "\\_\\_\\_\\_\\_");`

I don't see the `"\"` character in my replaced string, I would expect it to show me `"Hello \_\_\_\_\_"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
str = str.replaceAll("World", "\\\\_\\\\_\\\\_\\\\_\\\\_");
```

[**See it.**](http://www.ideone.com/tDCCX)

`\` is the escape character in Java strings. So to mean a literal `\` you need to escape it with another `\` as `\\`.

`\` is the escape char for the regex engine as-well. So a `\\` in Java string will be sent to regex engine as `\` which is not treated literally but instead will be used to escape the following character.

To pass `\\` to regex engine you need to have `\\\\` in the Java string.

---

Since you are replacing a string (not pattern) with another string, there is really **no need for regex**, you can use the `replace` method of the `String` class as:

```
input = input.replace("World", "\\_\\_\\_\\_\\_");
```

[**See it.**](http://www.ideone.com/A3mHH)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use 4 backslashes to insert a single one.

The point is: in literal java strings the backslash is an escape character so the literal string "\" is a single backslash. But in regular expressions, the backslash is also an escape character. The regular expression \ matches a single backslash. This regular expression as a Java string, becomes "\\".

So try something like this:

```
String str = "hello world";
System.out.println(str.replace("world","\\\\_\\\\_\\\\_\\\\"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall) post.