# Wrong output using replaceall

Tags: java, string

Why do i get "AAAAAAAAA" instead of "1A234A567" from following Code:

```
String myst = "1.234.567";

String test = myst.replaceAll(".", "A");

System.out.println(test);
```

Any Idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`replaceAll` function take a regular expression as parameter. And the regular expression "." means "any character". You have to escape it to specify that it is the character you want : `replaceAll("\\.", "A")`

Answer (score 7):

**Try this:**

```
String test = myst.replace(".", "A");
```

The difference: 
[`replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29) interprets the pattern as a regular expression, [`replace()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2C%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) interprets it as a string literal.

Here's the relevant source code from `java.lang.String` (indented and commented by me):

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex)
                  .matcher(this)
                  .replaceAll(replacement);
}


public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(
              target.toString(),
              Pattern.LITERAL /* this is the difference */
           ).matcher(this)
            .replaceAll(
                Matcher.quoteReplacement(
                    /* replacement is also a literal,
                       not a pattern substitution */
                    replacement.toString()
            ));
}
```

**Reference:**

- [`String.replaceAll(String,
  String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29)
- [`String.replace(CharSequence,
  CharSequence)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence%2C%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)
- [`Pattern.LITERAL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#LITERAL)

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `.`

make it

```
String myst = "1.234.567";

String test = myst.replaceAll("\\.", "A");

System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because every single char of the input matches the regexp pattern (`.`). To replace dots, use this pattern: `\.` (or as a Java String: `"\\."`).