# Java replaceAll function of string does not replace

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrong output using replaceall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179449/wrong-output-using-replaceall)

If I have string:

```
String test = "replace()thisquotes";

test = test.replaceAll("()", "");
```

the test result is still: `test = "replace()thisquotes"`

so () is not replaced.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would like to have: replacethisquotes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need regex, so use:

```
test.replace("()", "")
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you probably want to use [`String.replace`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) in this case as you don't need regular expressions.

---

For reference however, when using [`String.replaceAll`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), the first argument (which is interpreted as a regular expression) needs to be quoted, preferably by using  [`Pattern.quote`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String test = "replace()thisquotes";

test = test.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("()"), "");
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

System.out.println(test);  // prints "replacethisquotes"
```

Comment: "the first argument ... needs to be quoted" in addition, the second argument also needs to be quoted for replacement stuff

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of replaceAll function is a regular expression. "(" character is a special character in regular expressions.
Use this :

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String test = "replace()thisquotes";
      test = test.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
      System.out.println(test);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape `()` as these are characters reserved for regular exressions:

```
String test = "replace()thisquotes";
test = test.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = test.replaceAll("\\(\\)", "").
```

Java replace all uses regular expressions so in your example "()" is an empty group, use escape character '\".

Answer (score 0):

You have to quote your String first because parenthesis are special characters in regular expressions. Have a look at `Pattern.qutoe(String s)`.

```
test = test.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("()"), "");
```