# How to replace ' \' with '/' in a Java string?

Tags: java, string

I have a file name which is stored in a String variable `path`.
I tried this:

```
path = path.replaceAll('\','/')
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You have to escape your backslashes with another \. So in a path, use \\

Comment: You need to use escape character.

Comment: This was clear, but please also post any error messages you get to help us find the answer ;)

Comment: This doesn't deserve its own question.

Comment: +1 to compensate for downvotes , as i feel this is a legitimate problem and any newbie can get trapped.

Comment: This question seems not to be the "silly question" most of us thought after first reading it.

Comment: @MukulGoel a newbie should have searched and found this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

Comment: @all who downvoted in first place. Please see all below answers including mine , most of the answers are confused around the problem. So please look in depth of problem before downvote and not at its simplicity. Regards

Comment: @MukulGoel: The question itself is legitimate. My downvote is for saying "this does not work" without any details (compilation error, etc.), despite comments asking for them.

Comment: @interjay. Got you.. Yup right.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`replaceAll()` needs `Strings` as parameters.
So, if you write

```
path = path.replaceAll('\', '/');
```

it fails because you should have written

```
path = path.replaceAll("\", "/");
```

But this also fails because character '\' should be typed '\\'.

```
path = path.replaceAll("\\", "/");
```

And this will fail during execution giving you a `PatternSyntaxException`, because the fisr `String` is a regular expression (Thanks @Bhavik Shah for pointing it out). So, writing it as a RegEx, as @jlordo gave in his answer:

```
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Is what you were looking for.

To make optimal your core, you should make it independent of the Operating System, so use @Thai Tran's tip:

```
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", File.separator);
```

But this fails throwing an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` (I don't know why). It works if you use `replace()` with no regular expressions:

```
path = path.replace("\\", File.separator);
```

Comment: this gives PatternSyntaxException

Comment: It works fine for me with: path.replaceAll("\\\\", File.separator);

Comment: If throwed me an `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception under  `Windows XP` (in Spanish locale). Still don't know why.

Answer (score 13):

If it is a file path, you should try "File.separator" instead of '\' (in case your application works with Nix platform)

Comment: +1 for looking deep in the OP's problem and showing the best answer even for future correctness.

Comment: `The way it should be` , great.

Comment: Can you edit to give a code example?

Comment: @Thai Any example code on how to use it?

Comment: The code would totally depend on the way he created the variable 'path'. If he use the separator, then this escaping problem could be avoid. Draft code could be: path = File.separator + "home" + File.separator + "user" + File.separator + "file.txt";

Answer (score 9):

Your `path=path.replaceAll('\','/');` will not compile, because you have to escape the backslash,

use `path=path.replace('\\','/');` (it will replace all Occrurences, see JavaDoc)

or `path=path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");` (this regex escapes the backslash) ;-)

In the comments there is an explanation, why you need 4 of "\" to make the correct regex for one "\".

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum 

shows that `\\` is a regular expression construct for backslash. Still dont understand why we need `\\\\` , explain

Comment: yes, a backslash is also a special character in regexes. So in a string, this would be one backslash: `"\\"`, to escape the backslash in a regex, it has to be preceded with a backslash, just as in a string, so you need two backslashes for one backslash in a regex. Two backslashes look like this: `"\\\\"`. Hope this clarified it a bit

Comment: ahaaaan... alright.. get it.. cool.. please update your answer with this information. thanks

Comment: thanks this works path=path.replaceAll("\\\\","/")

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `replace` method and escape the backslash:

```
path = path.replace('\\', '/');
```

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
public String replace(char oldChar, char newChar)
```

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of
>   oldChar in this string with newChar.

Comment: That doesn't compile.
You should write `replaceAll("\\",`

Comment: Use [String.replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char, char)) it will replace all chars, replaceAll takes a regex, and i see a PatternSyntaxException flying around here!

Answer (score 1):

As it is a file path you have absolutely no need whatsoever to do this operation at all. Java understands both syntaxes. If you are trying to convert a File to a URL or URI, it has methods to do that.

Answer (score -1):

the `\` is not just some character in java.

it has its significance, some characters when preceeded by `\` have a special meaning,

refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html)  section `escape sequence` for details

Thus if you want to use just `\` in your code, there is an implementation `\\` for it.

So replace

```
path=path.replaceAll("\","/")
```

with

```
path=path.replaceAll("\\","/")
```

And this will fail during execution giving you a `PatternSyntaxException`, because the first String is a regular expression So based on @jlordo answer , this is the way to go

```
path = path.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Comment: It doesn't compile.
`replaceAll()` needs Strings as parameters.

Comment: @J.A.I.L. , yea I posted that way but updated it right before your comment. Thanks for the info though

Comment: -1 ?? Whats wrong with the answer??? :-/

Comment: replaceAll takes a regex, and this will be a PatternSyntaxException...

Comment: @MukulGoel but its still wrong!! see my answer

Comment: @jlordo yup.. you are right.. its still wrong :D , Thanks for the info on `why` for it.

Comment: Updated the answer based on @jlordo answer

Answer (score -1):

```
   String s="m/j/"; 
   String strep="\\\\";
   String result=s.replaceAll("/", strep);
    System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: this will solve your problem...

Comment: His problem is that he has a String like "m\j\" and wants to transform it to "m/j/".