# how can i remove character '\' from a string?

Tags: android, string, replace

A string I retrieved from database contains \ which i need to remove.But as I put the replaceAll function it marks an error. Anyone got help please???

```
String I retrieved: Bebo\'b
String required: Bebo'b
```

I tried this function: `str.replaceAll("\","");` marks an error where str is the retrieved string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use function `str.replaceAll("\\'","'");`

Comment: He already tried and mentioned in his question.

Comment: @Digital_Reality Sorry its been edited.

Comment: This is incorrect and will result in `PatternSyntaxException`

Comment: @crv str.replaceAll("\\",""); this is not work.

Comment: Use this code of piece String aa=ss.replaceAll("'\'","");

Comment: @laalto: public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 String s="bb\'dfr";
 TextView tx;

 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  tx=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
  tx.setText(s.replaceAll("\\'", "'"));
 }

 
}         it worked for me..........whole code

Answer (score 3):

You should try the `.replace("\", "")` function. Otherwise you can try `str.replaceAll("\'\", "");` using '\' as the escape sequence.

Comment: Neither will work. First one will be a syntax error at compile time, second one will give `PatternSyntaxException` at runtime.

Comment: Oh I see the issue. Sorry about that. Check again. I have made edits. Use the second method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String result=str.replaceAll("\'\'", "");
```

Though `"\"` treated as escape sequence character so it's single `"\"` is not workable .

Comment: This will result in `PatternSyntaxException`

Comment: @laalto I have modified and it's workable. I have tested it. Thanks. I have done little mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

> use this code.

String ss="Bebo\'b";
          String aa=ss.replaceAll("'\'","");
          tv.setText(aa);

Answer (score 2):

This is a delimeter collision problem. You ha ve to do;

str.replaceAll("\\\\","");

Here is another thread about it.

[String replace a Backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
str.replaceAll("\\","");
```

Or

```
str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\'"), "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class XYZ {     
public static void main(String argss[])     {
        String p="123\' 5677fg\' ffd";
        System.out.println(p.replaceAll("/", ""));  }

}
```

try this

Comment: he wants to replace backslash, not `/`

Comment: did u try this first try its working and getting desired output :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Bebo\\'b";
str.replaceAll("\\","");
System.out.println(str);
```