# How to replace all \ with / in my string

Tags: java, android, replace

In my android program I want to replace all backslash(`\`) with slash(`/`) in a string.
Replace All did not work for that.So please help me.

Comment: Post code and say exactly what's the problem.

Comment: file\folder\a.png,this is the string but i want the string as file/folder/a.png.

Comment: You want to change in the code ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String replace a Backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

Answer (score 1):

Try `text.replace('\\', '/')` where `text` is a String.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code:

```
String origString = "file\\folder\\a.png";
String newString = origString.replaceAll("\\\\","/");
System.out.println (newString);
```

**Output:**

```
file/folder/a.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String test = ...
test.replace("\\", "/");
```