# Input1 = input.replaceAll not working

Tags: java, replaceall

So I have a scanner that takes in a string and saves it to input then I try to do

```
    input.replaceAll("?/.,!' ", "");
```

and print the line below to test it but it just doesn't replace anything

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Test2 {
        public static void main (String[]args){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter a sentence: ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();

            int x, strCount = 0;
            String str1;

            str1 = str.replaceAll(",.?!' ", "");

            System.out.println(str1);

            for (x = 0; x < str1.length(); x++)
            {
                strCount++;
            }
            System.out.println("Character Count is: " + strCount);

       }

    }
```

Here is the code I am working with. all I need is to replace all punctuation and spaces with nothing.

Comment: you need to put your code inside the `for` loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [String replace a Backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

Comment: Try this instead:

    `str1 = str.replaceAll("[\\p{Punctuation}\\p{Space_Separator}]", "");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line :

```
str.replaceAll(",.?!' ", "");
```

will search the entire string ",.?!' " to be replaced.
The argument of the replaceAll method is a regex.

So, it will surely be better with something like that :

```
str.replaceAll("[,.?!' ]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter must be a regular expression, here alternative character classes `[ ... ]`.

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[?/.,!' ]", "");
```

or more generalized s=whitespace, Punct=punctuation:

```
String str1 = str.replaceAll("[\\s\\p{Punct}]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the characters `,.?!` appear together in the input `String` no replacement will be made. You could use a character class to specify a range of characters

```
str1 = str.replaceAll("[,.?!' ]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` takes a regular expression as the first argument, so it needs to be formatted as such:

```
str1 = str.replaceAll("[,.?!' ]", "");
```

More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html