# Remove single quotes in a string Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I need some help to replace all the single quotes in a string.

This is my string:

```
String myString = "The State of the water = 'ICE'";

// I want to remove the single quotes around ICE

System.out.println(myString); // The State of the water = ICE
```

Comment: Did you take a look at `String.replace()` method?

Comment: i just googled the title of your question - the results were shocking

Comment: possible duplicate of [String replace a Backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash) or at least very similar (no need for separate question for replacing any possible character)

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace String with another in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216272/replace-string-with-another-in-java)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("\'","");
```

Comment: Is the escape character required?

Comment: Not at all. It's a habit ;)

Comment: Please prefer `replace` over `replaceAll` if you do not need REGEX (as shown here). The naming is unfortunate, but `replace` also repales **all** occurences.

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
String str = "The State of the water = 'ICE'";
str = str.replaceAll("'","");
```

Comment: This will replace all single apostrophes, not just those round `ICE`.

Comment: Please prefer `replace` over `replaceAll` if you do not need REGEX (as shown here). The naming is unfortunate, but `replace` also repales **all** occurences.