# JSONObject is not created correctely

Tags: java, json

I create `JsonObject` and `JsonArray` as following:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
jObj.put("path", "dfds/g");
jObj.put("etag", "dfdsfsd");
jObj.put("size_bytes", 123);
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
list.add(jObj);
String s = list.toJSONString();
```

The result I get:

```
[{"size_bytes":123,"etag":"dfdsfsd","path":"dfds\/g"}]
```

1. I expect  the path component to be `"path":"dfds\g"`, not `dfds\/g`
2. I need the field to be in order as I they in the code, but they are  not as I expected:`path, etag, size_bytes`
   I`ll be glad to get an advices how to solve the above issues

Comment: The order of elements in your object should not matter, you should be able to convert to and from `JSON` regardless. The `backslash` is appearing to escape the `forwardslash`

Answer (score 4):

The Json encoder is escaping your forward slash which is why you're getting `\/`.  This is completely legal syntax and not something to worry about.

You shouldn't need to worry about ordering inside a Json string, fields are inherently not ordered and relying on this could well lead to issues for you in the future.

Comment: The json string is sent to other process it expect the path to be without '\': Can`t read 'dfds\/g', expects 'dfds\g'

Comment: Use a JSON decoder rather than trying to do it by hand would be my best suggestion

Comment: I form json string and send it to other process. that process is 3 party. I just know it expect path without '\'

Comment: Have you actually tried sending it? If the 3rd party is being sensible they will be able to handle this just fine.

Comment: I sent it - it didn`t work properly. Looks that there the order of tags and backslash are important

Comment: Ok so the 3rd party, no matter what they say are *not* using a JSON format at all.  Can you have them fix this at their end?

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely **MUST** remove the forward slash from your string then you can do this:

```
s = s.replace("\\/", "/");
```

See [String replace a Backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash) for more information.

I recommend not doing this in this circumstance. Instead you should parse the `String` using one of the many `JSON` parsing libraries.

Here is an example of this in action with your sample `String`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "[{\"size_bytes\":123,\"etag\":\"dfdsfsd\",\"path\":\"dfds\\/g\"}]";
    
    System.out.println(s);
    
    s = s.replace("\\/", "/");
    
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

**Output:**

> `[{"size_bytes":123,"etag":"dfdsfsd","path":"dfds\/g"}]`
>
> `[{"size_bytes":123,"etag":"dfdsfsd","path":"dfds/g"}]`

Comment: I am not doing parsing . I just should send the string having correct format to other proccess. that process is 3 party. I just know it expect path without '\'

Comment: @Yakov well then doing the `s.replace()` should work, ymmv