# Backslashes not able to remove from String

Tags: java, json

```
       byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes((Paths.get("txt.json")));

        String data = new String(jsonData,"UTF-8");
        data= data.replaceAll("[\\r\\n]+", "");
        data= data.replaceAll("\\t", "");

        data= data.replaceAll("\\\\","");
        response.setResponse(data);
```

data i am getting like this

```
       \"abs\": \"abc\",\"dff\": [{\"dff\": [{\"rtr\": \"dfg\",\"fdgdfg\"
```

but i need to remove slashes

```
        "abs": "abc","dff": [{"dff": [{"rtr": "dfg","fdgdfg"
```

please Help me what changes i need to do

Comment: `data= data.replaceAll("\\\"","\"");` should suffice.

Comment: Stop. What is the content of `txt.json`? Why do you need to replace escape characters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String replace a Backslash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596458/string-replace-a-backslash)

Comment: **How** are you "getting like this" ? Are you printing it on the console? Or are you using a json library to output it as JSON? (Or something else) I'm guessing you're outputing it using a JSON library as a string, which will add the backslashes back in, logically, to make it a valid json string.

Comment: txt.Json File is JSON file, i am trying to read from json file and convert to String

Comment: *i am trying to read from json file and convert to String* **why? Why not convert it to JSON**

Comment: {
"abc": "fgf",
 "fbdf": [{
"fdgdfg": [{
"fg": "gfdf",
"fdgd": "dfgUs:"}, {
"fidfg": "contafdgber","lafdgel": "(800) 206-9469"
}],
"ldfg": [{
"gfdd": "fgdfel",                                                        this is Txt.JSON

Comment: I have tried all methods , and Previously asked questions, but Slashes still displaying

Comment: i need to attach it into a JSON response, that is why i am trying to convert to string and attaching to JSON Response, is this the right Way? or how can i read from ?JSON file and attach it to a JSON response?

Comment: Show the real code that generates the output. We don't know what you mean with "attaching to json response". What kind of object is `response` on which you call `response.setResponse` ? What do you do with this `response` to get the output that you're showing above?

Answer (score 0):

Use replace() instead of replaceAll():

```
data = data.replace("\\","");
```

Comment: Any particular reason?

Comment: Of course: replace() is a simple string replacement. replaceAll() uses regular expressions.

Comment: But how does that answer the question?

Comment: easier to read than `replaceAll("\\\\", "")` and probably more effecient

Comment: He wants to remove all backslashes, doesn't he? Backslash is an escape character in regular expressions.

Comment: @Christian Yes, and that's why the OP already escaped it. This solution is no different than what the OP is already doing. And ScareWombat, it's not more efficient (in all current Java versions) - because String.replace invokes String.replaceAll, after escaping all characters that need to be escaped.