# how do i replace any string with a "$ " in java?

Tags: java

Using `replaceAll()` is giving me a rexex exception.

This is the code I am using:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text= "This is to be replaced &1 ";
        text = text.replaceAll("&1", "&");
        System.out.println(text);   
    }
}
```

EXCEPTION:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal group reference
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:7)
```

Comment: Compiling and running this code on Java 1.6 produces no exception...

Comment: I ran your code, and it runs fine.

Comment: By convention the first letter of java classes must be written with capital letters in this case Test

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Comment: Bartzilla:  Convention only suggests that the first letter of java classes be a capital letter.  It will still run perfectly fine if it is in lower case.

Answer (score 4):

Seems to work fine for me. http://ideone.com/7qR6Z

But for something this simple, you can avoid regex and just use `string.replace()`

```
text = text.replace("&1", "&");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, that was a simple misconception i had.

Comment: `String.replace()` takes only char as parameters. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @Marcelo there is another that takes charsequence which is string.

Comment: @Bala R Can't find it in the javadoc at all :s

Comment: @Marcelo Your javadoc link is for 1.4.2.  it's listed in javaoc for 1.5. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html not sure why it's not listed in 1.6 but it's definitely there. ( besides they will not remove a method just like that; they will deprecate it).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want regex then use [String#replace](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method instead like this:

```
"This is to be replaced &1 ".replace("&1", "&")
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution for this error while replacing with "$" sign was to replace all "$" with "\\$" like in code bellow:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\$", "\\\\\\$");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pattern.quote() to compile any string into a regular expression. Try:

```
public class test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text= "This is to be replaced &1 ";
        text = text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("&1"), "&");
        System.out.println(text);   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, your code works fine. However, if you mistyped or something and actually have

```
text = text.replaceAll("&1", "$");
```

Then you DO have to escape the replacement:

```
text = text.replaceAll("&1", "\\$");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question title shows `how do i replace any string with a “$ ” in java?` but your question text says `String text= "This is to be replaced &1 "`

If you're actually trying to replace a dollar sign, this is a special character in regular expressions, you need to escape it with a backslash.  You need to escape that backslash, because blackslash is a special character in Java, so assuming dollar sign is what you intended:

`String text = "This is to be replaced $1 ";`

`text = text.replaceAll("\\$1", "\\$");`

`System.out.println(text);`

EDIT: Clarify some text