# How to replace a back slash with another character in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying the following code in Java in which I need to replace a back slash with a forward slash but I can't.

```
package superpkg;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

final public class Super
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
         String string="xxx\\aaa";

         string.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
         System.out.println(string);

         string.replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\"), "/");
         System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

---

In both the cases, it displays the following output.

```
xxx\aaa
xxx\aaa
```

means that the back slash in the given string is not replaced with the forward slash as expected. How can it be achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Comment: @ringbearer: This is not a duplicate of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Java.  You need to assign the result of `replaceAll` somewhere:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are immutable so you need to do

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning `string` its new value.
Do this instead `string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "/");`

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable. There is no mean to modify a string in-place, every method called on String returns a new String.

In your code, string.replaceAll(...) returns a String but you don't reassign it to your "string" variable, so the result is lost.
Use this instead :

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "xxx\\aaa";
    string = string.replace("\\", "/");
    System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.String` is immutable.
So you should assign result of your API call to a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args)  
{ 
     String string="xxx\\aaa"; 

     string = string.replaceAll("\\\\", "/"); 

     System.out.println(string); 
}
```