# How to replace multiple slash and backslash in a string with a single one?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

My goal is to replace all "/" and "\" with one "\".

**Input:**

```
String path = "H\\\\\\\\\\ello///Wo\\rld\\!////";
```

**Output:**

```
String path = "H\ello\Wo\rld\!\";
```

**Question:**

Is there a way to do that all in one single line?

My solution (working!):

1. change all to the same char
2. replace all "/" with one Slash
3. put it back to normal

I learned that I need regex and that "[X]+" will put all possible combinations eg. "XXfXfXXXX" to "XfXfX".

I am searching for something like: (pseudocode)

```
path = path.replaceAll("[\\/]+", "\\");
```

I tried some combinations of that but everytime it throw errors.

**My Solution:**

```
path = path.replace("\\", "/");
path = path.replaceAll("[/]+", "/");

pfad = pfad.replace("/", "\\");
```

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to iterate here thru the chars one by one

Comment: Why do you want to replace ``\`` with ``\``? It doesn't change anything. Do you perhaps want to replace *series* of ``\`` and `/` with single ``\``?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am aiming for @Pshemo

Comment: Try `.replaceAll("[\\\\/]+", "\\\\")` if all chunks of 1 or more ``\`` and `/` chars should be replaced with one ``\``.

Comment: Like I said, my solution works with that 3 steps, just thinking about if there s a way to put it in one replaceAll()

Comment: What should be result of replacing ``\\\\//``? Should it be one ``\`` or maybe two ``\\`` (one for ``\\\\`` sequence and second for `//` sequence)?

Comment: Are the strings in your example not escaped? Are you manipulating source code? I'm confused since the second string is a syntax error

Comment: My apologies if i confused you. No, I am not trying to manipulate "The Matrix" :D. It s just a short pic of a bigger problem. Of course it would be \\ in a String but I am not trying to get a "real" String as result. I missed one \ after "rld\" too

Comment: See https://ideone.com/xhUr8C. One backslash is missing in your string literal before `!`, I added it there.

Comment: @xentus I believe my first-posted solution in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904397/how-to-replace-multiple-slash-and-backslash-in-a-string-with-a-single-one/55905751#comment98464405_55904397) is your answer. If yes, please consider accepting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55905751/3832970).

Answer (score 4):

Try this pattern to match groups of slashes and backslashes: `(?:\\+|\/+)` and replace it with `\\`.

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - noncapturing group

`\\+` - match one or more `\`

`\/+` - match one or more `/`

`|` - alternation: match pattern on the right or on the left

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiWtXP/1)

Alternatively you could use pattern `[\/\\]+`, which matches one or more of `\` or `/`

[Another demo](https://regex101.com/r/oiWtXP/1)

Comment: This won't work if there's a mix of back- and forward-slashes. E.g. `H\\\\///\\\ello///Wo\\rld\!/\//`. It might be good enough for OP though ;)

Comment: @SamWhan That's why I included alternative, which would work in your scenario :)

Comment: Simply `[\\\/]+` is sufficient

Comment: @Strelok That's why I also suggested it

Comment: @MichałTurczyn both of your examples do not produce correct result for "H\\\\///\\\ello///Wo\\rld\!/\//" or at least what I think it should be ("H\ello\Wo\rld\!\")

Comment: Thx for the answers! It is nice to see that it is also possible to group them but of course best case would be to get all variations of '/' n '\'.
Unfortunatly I get some errors:

Comment: I tried smth like the alternativ myself "[\/\\]+" , "[\\\/]+" results in: 
`test.java:6: error: illegal escape character`

Comment: Edit: pfad.replaceAll -> path.replaceAll

Comment: @xentus you need escape also escape character, so you need to write \\/ instead of just \/ ( you need to escape it first in a code, then in regular expression)

Comment: No need to escape `/` char, it is not any special in a regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
.replaceAll("[\\\\/]+", "\\\\")
```

See the regex graph:

[image]

The `[\\/]+` pattern matches `\` or `/` one or more times. The replacement pattern is `\\` since a backslash in the replacement pattern is *special* in Java, it is used to escape the `$` symbol that denotes a literal `$` char. To match a literal backslash, you need to [use four `\` in the regex string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9113449/3832970).

See [Java demo online](https://ideone.com/xhUr8C):

```
String path = "H\\\\\\\\\\ello///Wo\\rld\\!////";
System.out.println(path.replaceAll("[\\\\/]+", "\\\\"));
// => H\ello\Wo\rld\!\
```