# How do I find and replace all escaped quotes and regular quotes with different values?

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking to replace all occurrences of an escaped quote (\") with (\\\") in the string, then replacing all remaining unescaped quotes (") with escaped quotes (\").  Here's what I tried so far:

```java
row = row.replaceAll("\\\\(?>\")", "\\\\\"");
row = row.replaceAll("((?<!\\\\)\")", "\"");
```

Example Input:
`"This is a test with \" and "'s where \" is replaced with triple \'s before "`

Example Output: `\"This is a test with \\\" and \"'s where \\\" is replaced with triple \'s before \"`

`\\(?>\")"` works on https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output in replaceAll doesn't find escaped quotes.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: @Mandy8055 Nope, that catches all \'s not just the ones that prefix quotes.  So "This is a test with \ and \" ..." both \'s get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace single backslash with triple backslash, then replace quotes with backslash-quote:

```
row = row.replaceAll("\\\\(?!')", "\\\\\\\\\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

Comment: That won't work with \'s that are alone right?  I.e. "test \ \"" will return "test \\ \\\"" rgiht?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to have four \'s to find a .  I used a lookback and forward to find \".  Credit to [java, regular expression, need to escape backslash in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113328/java-regular-expression-need-to-escape-backslash-in-regex/9113449#:~:text=In%20short%2C%20you%20always%20need,as%20the%20escaped%20backslash%20character).

`"\\\\(?>\")"` will find \".

`"(?<!\\\\)\""` will find "'s without \ before it.

So the solution I found to do both is:

```java
        Pattern escapePattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\(?>\")");
        Pattern quotePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\\\)\"");

        for(String row : rows.split("\n")) {
            Matcher escapeMatcher = escapePattern.matcher(row.trim());
            String escapedString = escapeMatcher.replaceAll("\\\\\\\\\\\\\"");

            Matcher quoteMatcher = quotePattern.matcher(escapedString);
            queryRows.add(quoteMatcher.replaceAll("\\\\\""));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

first replace single ( \ ) with ( \\ ) and then replace ( " ) with ( \" )

```
row = row.replace("\\", "\\\\").replace("\"", "\\\"");
```