# Replace a special character with other special character within string

Tags: java

I want to replace a special character " with \" in string.
I tried str = str.replaceAll("\"","\\\");
But this doesnt work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backslash problem with String.replaceAll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 2):

The closing quotes are missing in the 2nd parameter. Change to:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\"","\\\\\"");
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/p49wQ).

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the \ by doubling it:\\

Code example:

```
String tt = "\\\\terte\\";
System.out.println(tt);
System.out.println(tt.replaceAll("\\\\", "|"));
```

This gives the following output:

```
\\terte\
||terte|
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.replaceAll() API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular
>   expression with the given replacement.
>
> An invocation of this method of the form str.replaceAll(regex, repl)
>   yields exactly the same result as the expression
>
> ```
> Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
> ```
>
> Note that backslashes () and dollar signs ($) in the replacement
>   string may cause the results to be different than if it were being
>   treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use
>   Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special
>   meaning of these characters, if desired.

[Btw, it is duplicated question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839)

Comment: You should always point to the latest api.  You are pointing to 1.4.2