# Single quote JSP to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, escaping

I have a string that must be used to be passed into a JavaScript function. I have tried many ways, but I still cannot make it to work.

```
<a href="javascript:goFac('<%=name%>')"><%=name%></a>
```

The name field is a string that contains single quotes such as *It's Morning*. I have tried to use:

```
String nameString = rs.getString("name");
nameString = nameString.replaceAll("'","\'");

<a href="javascript:goFac('<%=nameString %>')"><%=nameString%></a>
```

And also

```
nameString = URLEncoder.encode(nameString);
```

And also

```
nameString = nameString.replaceAll("'","&#39;");
```

And also

```
 nameString = nameString.replaceAll("'","&apos;");
```

I still cannot get it to work. And also I can't go for EL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace a single quote (') in a String with a JavaScript-escaped (backslashed) single quote (\') in Java code then you need to escape the backslash character (with a backslash!). For example:

```
nameString = nameString.replaceAll("'","\\'");
```

See also: [String.replaceAll single backslashes with double backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **String.fromCharCode(39)** instead of single quote, String.fromCharCode(39) is ASCII codes for single quote.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, as the HTML encoding is done before the function call and replaced the single quote with `&#39;`.

```
nameString = nameString.replaceAll("&#39;","\\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it inside JSP tag, you need to have sufficient backslashes for one of them to actually make it into the web page.  The code would be:

```
<a href="javascript:goFac('<%=nameString.replaceAll("'", "\\\\'") %>')"><%=nameString%></a>
```

You need one backslash to escape the other backslash and each of those needs to be escaped - hence four backslashes (yuck).

Hope that helps.