# Is there any method of JFileChooser which can provide me a file's path with Double slash "\\"?

Tags: java, jfilechooser

In Netbeans I am using a JFileChooser to get a file's path. All is OK and its giving me the path as well with single slash `\`. But I need the path with double slash `\\`. So my question is, is there already any kind of method which can provide me that type of path? I also don't know the name of the path which has double slash `\\`. Example- `H:\\New folder\\odesk\\odeskViolin4.wav`
What can I do now?

Comment: The question is why (do you need double dashes)?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am trying to play a .wav file after getting the file by the JFileChooser

Comment: That's, you receive a `File` reference from `JFileChooser`, why do you need double dashes?  The only reason to use double dashes is when you create the `String` yourself and need to escape the slash character.  The requirements make no sense.  The in ability to find the file has nothing to do with the slashes...

Comment: @MadProgrammer dashes and the slashes, are they same things? I am confused

Comment: Your confused, sorry, slashes...massive headache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply replace the `\` symbols with `\\`, by using the `String.replaceAll()` method.

```
String input = "C:\\Users\\myName"; //special characters have to be escaped.
String doubleSlashed = input.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
System.out.println(doubleSlashed);
```

This will print:

```
C:\\Users\\myName
```

Note that `String.replaceAll(String pattern, String replacement)` takes two arguments and in my example they are four-slashed and eight-slashed strings. This is because the `\` symbol is a special character and has to be escaped.

Comment: Does your solution actually run for you? I get `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1` when I try. [EDIT: Found a solution, you have to use `input.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/backslash-problem-with-string-replaceall)

Comment: Not the down voter, but this seems a *very* odd requirement.  Better to wait for the answer to @Mad's question before rushing in.

Comment: @kocko I am having a error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you truly want to replace single backslashes with double backslashes, you could simply do this:

```
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
```

However, you may not actually want double backslashes, depending on your purpose. You should at least be aware of this:

```
String oneBackSlash   = "\\";    //This String will consist of one backslash
String twoBackSlashes = "\\\\";  //This String will consist of two backslashes
//The String below has no double backslashes, only single ones
String path = "H:\\New folder\\odesk\\odeskViolin4.wav";

System.out.println(oneBackSlash);
System.out.println(twoBackSlashes);
System.out.println(path);
```

Output:

```
\
\\
H:\New folder\odesk\odeskViolin4.wav
```