# How to find a file path in current java directory

Tags: filepath

I have a function that gets a file path as an input. input file is located in a folder in my project (etc/xsd/template.xsd). how can i set this path?

this ia my function:

JAXBUtilityTool tool = new JAXBUtilityTool("etc/xsd/template.xsd","src.com.classes");

and  it can not find the file "etc/xsd/template.xsd"

System.getProperty("user.dir") does not help since when I add the rest of path to it:

```
             System.getProperty("user.dir")+ "etc/xsd/template.xsd"
```

result is c:\eclipse\myworkingdirectory\project/etc/xsd/template.xsd

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
path = path.replaceAll("\\","/") + "/etc/xsd/template.xsd"
```

Source:

[String.replaceAll single backslashes with double backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-with-backslashes-error)

Comment: I do not know why! but it works with path in c:/eclipse/myworkingdirectory/project/etc/xsd/template.xsd form not using \ so if i want to replace \ with / what is the characters I should use : string.replaceall("\", ?????)