# escaping backslash in java string literal

Tags: java, string, escaping, backslash

I am using Java for a while and come up with this problem:
I use hard-coded paths in windows like

```
"D:\Java-code\JavaProjects\workspace\eypros\src"
```

The problem is that I need to escape the backslash character in order to use it with string. So I manually escape each backslash:

```
"D:\\Java-code\\JavaProjects\\workspace\\eypros\\src"
```

Is there a way to automatically take the unescaped path and return an escaped java string.

I am thinking that maybe another container besides java string could do the trick (but I don't know any).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there any downsides to just using forward-slashes?

Comment: What do you mean by "take" the unescaped path? This is just in source code, after all - if you have user input, you won't need to escape it.

Comment: [Andrei's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23363356/2187042) regarding `System.getProperty("file.separator");` deals with a lot of the system dependant problems you're going to suffer if you go down this path (but not all). Is there a particular reason you want to lock your program to windows? Personally I would put all your user files within their home directory, which you can get the directory of without any system specific code

Comment: JAVA accepts forward slash `/` as cross platform file separator. So, it is safe to use on `Windows` platform too.

Answer (score 20):

```
public static String escapePath(String path)
{
    return path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
}
```

The `\` is doubled since it must be escaped in those strings also.

Anyway, I think you should use `System.getProperty("file.separator");` instead of `\`.

Also the `java.io.File` has a few methods useful for file-system paths.

Comment: This code will work fine. But is this code really needed? You need to escape the back-slashes only when you are hardcoding the path. And if you are hardcoding, then anyways you need to manually encode the "\"...

Comment: I don't know the use-case of the user. Maybe he is reading those paths from a file that a client can modify.

Comment: By the way, if you use replaceAll instead of replace, it will give you an error. Check the reason and solution (replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\")) [here][link]:  [link][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes]