# How do I replace the string "/" with "\\" in Java?

Tags: java

`String s=o.replace ("/","\\");` replaces "/" with "\", but what I actually need is to replace it with "\\ "instead.

How can I do so?

Comment: Use 4 backslashes: "\\\\"

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish something with a Windows-style path?  What are you really after?  Kind of feels like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Please try to research before asking questions here.

Comment: Question seems fine to me. Please refer to a duplicate if you downvote it for that reason.

Comment: possible duplicate of [escaping backslash in java string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363241/escaping-backslash-in-java-string-literal)

Answer (score 2):

you must escape each single "\", so if you want to replace a double backslash use:

```
String s = o.replace("/", "\\\\");
```

if you want to replace ALL occurences of "/" kepp the `replaceAll()`-Method in mind

//EDIT:
as said in the comments, `replace()` also replaces ALL occurences of the `String`, but `replaceAll()` can use regex.

Comment: Actually, `String.replace()` method DOES replace all occurences. The difference is that `replaceAll()` uses regex.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is [a reserved char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) and need to be escaped by one backslash:

`\\` means `\`, so you need 4 in your case.