# Java escape character replace with blank

Tags: java

Is it possible to make `\"type4\"` to `"type4"` in Java? Unable to find a way to escape this escape character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [escaping backslash in java string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363241/escaping-backslash-in-java-string-literal)

Comment: use string.replace to remove the `\\`? Could you add some context, or even better, a reproductible example? For now it's hard to see exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: Is `\"type4\"` the literal output you see (e.g. in a text file), or is that what you see in the console?

Comment: @jhamon While inserting a document in mongo, \ was used a escape character. The API response picks the '\' as  it is. I want to get rid of this '\' in API response.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I see \"type\" in API response as well as in a text file

Comment: @earl I attempted an answer below, though it seems somewhat dubious to me that this would be appearing in the API response, unless maybe it is JSON, in which case you should tell us this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is a JSON indeed

Comment: Then I doubt the text file has literal backslahses in it.  You should investigate whatever tool wrote the file, because it made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
String replaced = "\\\"type4\\\"".replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.