# Include Double Backslash as plain text symbols in a String

Tags: java, string, syntax, formatting, expression

I have a plain String where it contains "\". However Java seems to be trying to format the String when it sees the Double Backslash. Is there a way to tell the String to completely ignore Backslash formatting?

```
String Test = "File location is: C:\\Folder\\File.txt";
```

Output:

```
Test = "File location is: C:\Folder\File.txt"
```

Desired output:

```
Test = "File location is: C:\\Folder\\File.txt"
```

Comment: If you want a backslash in a string, you need to put ```\\``` in the string literal. If you want ```\\``` in a string, you need to put ```\\\\``` in the string literal.

Comment: You could try this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363241/escaping-backslash-in-java-string-literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363241/escaping-backslash-in-java-string-literal)

Comment: @khelwood, thanks a lot!. Could you repost your comment as an answer so I can cross it as solution :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public class Sample {

     public static void main(String[] args){
        String test = "File location is: C:\\\\Folder\\\\File.txt";
        System.out.println("Test = "+ test);
     }
}
```

Output :

```
Test = File location is: C:\\Folder\\File.txt
```