# Using backslash (\) inside a String variable in java

Tags: java, string, backslash

I am not able to get the message value in the desired format.

```
String url = "sample"
String message ="/test{\"url\":"' + url + '\"}
```

The desired value of `message` is `"/test{\"url\":\"sample\"}"`

Any idea on this?

Comment: you just copy the expected string then paste into ide, ide(in my case, intellij idea) will escape quotes for you.

Comment: @LeiYang, I want the url value to be picked up dynamically from the url variable

Comment: You need to escape slashes like this String message = "/test{\\\"url\\\":\\\"sample\\\"}";
You have another answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23363356/6584664

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
    String url = "sample";
    String message ="/test{\\\"url\\\":\""+url+"\\\"}";
```

Or you can use String.format:

```
    String url = "sample";
    String message = String.format("/test{\\\"url\\\":\"%s\\\"}",url);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following syntax:

```
String url = "sample";
String message ="/test{\\\"url\\\":\"" + url + "\\\"}";
```

Please note that back-slash `\` and double-quote `"` are specialized character and hence they need to be escaped using back-slash `\`.
Hence, `\\` is used for `\` and `\"` is used for `"` in String literal.

**Output:**

```
/test{\"url\":"sample\"}
```

Answer (score 1):

After several tried, I found the solution:

```
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("\"/test{");
    sb.append("\"\\");
    sb.append("\"");
    sb.append("url\\\"");
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append("\\\"");
    sb.append(url);
    sb.append("\"\\}\"");
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: url label is missing in message. It should be url: followed by url variable value

Comment: I updated the code.