# How to replace all backward slahes in java

Tags: java

I have a String which consists of backward slashes .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "\"json_value\": \"{\\\"screen\\\":\\\"SCR-3\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"200\\\",\\\"count\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Regular Cup, Delishy 50 Ml\\\",\\\"seat_num\\\":\\\"D12\\\",\\\"image\\\":\\\"http://192.168.2.46:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"orderid\\\":\\\"14070738\\\",\\\"itemid\\\":\\\"57\\\",\\\"vendor_id\\\":\\\"10101500072001001\\\",\\\"date_time\\\":\\\"13:07:38\\\",\\\"toppings\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Quantity      1\\\",\\\"value\\\":[\\\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML\\\"]},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Quantity      2\\\",\\\"value\\\":[\\\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML\\\"]}]}\",";


        str =   str.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");

        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

Could anybody please let me know how to replace all backward slashes ??

I tried using str = str.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"); , but its not replacing them .

Comment: replace one backslash with *what*?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-with-backslashes-error.

Comment: Replace all with empty

Comment: @user974802 `"\\\\\\\\"` is not really _empty_...

Comment: Well, this replaceAll does replace each \ with \\. So what...?

Comment: The syntax is: `public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`, therefore `"\\\\\\\\"` is not right. Maybe just `""` for the replacement?

Comment: @user974802 - Then do - `str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");`

Comment: @user974802 Perhaps you can learn to distinguish "replace" and "remove"? Certainly, "replacing some substring with the empty string" is "removing the substring", but you didn't say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String str = "\"json_value\": \"{\\\"screen\\\":\\\"SCR-3\\\",\\\"price\\\":\\\"200\\\",\\\"count\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Regular Cup, Delishy 50 Ml\\\",\\\"seat_num\\\":\\\"D12\\\",\\\"image\\\":\\\"http://192.168.2.46:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":\\\"2\\\",\\\"orderid\\\":\\\"14070738\\\",\\\"itemid\\\":\\\"57\\\",\\\"vendor_id\\\":\\\"10101500072001001\\\",\\\"date_time\\\":\\\"13:07:38\\\",\\\"toppings\\\":[{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Quantity      1\\\",\\\"value\\\":[\\\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML\\\"]},{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Quantity      2\\\",\\\"value\\\":[\\\"Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML\\\"]}]}\",";


  str =   str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");

  System.out.println(str);


 output: 


 "json_value": "{"screen":"SCR-3","price":"200","count":"0","name":"Regular Cup, Delishy 50 Ml","seat_num":"D12","image":"http://192.168.2.46:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg","quantity":"2","orderid":"14070738","itemid":"57","vendor_id":"10101500072001001","date_time":"13:07:38","toppings":[{"name":"Quantity      1","value":["Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML"]},{"name":"Quantity      2","value":["Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML"]}]}",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str =   str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Where is the problem???

Answer (score 1):

As `replaceAll()` treats the first argument as regex so you must double to escape the backslash

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

`\` is a special char in java while using it in string.So to treat `\` as normal character you need to place another `\` to turn off its special meaning in regex. So to write `\\` in regex you need to write it with four `\`