# Java: Replacing all URLs from String (URL contains '\') using replaceAll()

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am processing a corpus containing around 10 million files. Some files have urls containing a backslash ('\') inside them. I want to replace all the URLs from those file. The following works fine until it finds an URL containing a backslash.

```
public static String removeUrl(String str)
{
    String urlPattern = "((https?|ftp|gopher|telnet|file|Unsure):((//)|(\\\\))[\\w\\d:#@%/;$~_?\\+-=\\\\\\.&]*)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(urlPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (str!=null && m.find()) {
        str = str.replaceAll(m.group(0)," ").trim(); // ERROR is occuring here when m.group(0) has URL with '\'
    }
    return str;
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: Can you add some examples?

Comment: please told your required output in example

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with escaping the backslash:
`removeUrl("http://go.com\\\\")` doesnt throw the error, but `removeUrl("http://go.com\\")` does. You might have to manipulate the strings before you replaceAll, like `str.replaceAll("\\\\", "");`.

Also, the exception is only thrown if you `str.replaceAll("\\", "");`, and not `str.replace("\\", "");`

Edit: Just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes)

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for me.

```
[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_])+(:[0-9]+)?([\/\\][a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]*)*(\?(&?[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+=[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)+)?
```

It matches all of these

```
http://test.test.test:123/test.test/test?blah=23&bluh=23
http://test.test.test/test.test/?blah=blah
http://ttes-test.comsa234/ase/ase
abc://test.test
abc://test.test:900
abc://test.test/
abc://test.test\
abc://test.test\test
abc://test.test:90/test\test/test
abc://wow/test?this=works&and=worksagain
cde://yay/what/yes.com/hi_there\?param=value&param=value
withdash://its-dash/another-dash\okay
```

You can test with regex101