# How do I make multi replace() java

Tags: java, string, special-characters, newline, carriage-return

I have a string with `\r\n`, `\r`, `\n` or `\"` characters in it. How can I replace them faster?

What I already have is:

```
String s = "Kerner\\r\\n kyky\\r hihi\\n \\\"";
System.out.println(s.replace("\\r\\n", "\n").replace("\\r", "").replace("\\n", "").replace("\\", ""));
```

But my code does not look beautiful enough.
I found on the Internet something like:

```
replace("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n|\\", "")
```

I tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: When you say "more effective/faster/performancer", what do you mean by "more effective" and "performancer"?

Comment: Should be fairly easy to do using StringBuilder and charAt() with the original string

Comment: `but that doesnt works` ... what do you mean by this?  Your regex pattern correctly matches your current logic.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, that part what i found in internet doesnt work with '     replaceAll("\\r\\n|\\r|\\n|\\", "");' returned Kerner\r\n kyky\r hihi\n \"

Comment: @khelwood, I mean for equal funtion in java that can works faster.

Comment: @sausagerus So by "more effective/faster/performancer" you just mean "faster"

Comment: @khelwood, exactly ))) But I found out that 4 * replaceAll() works faster. Its looks ugly but quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a method, put `/r/n`, `/n` and `/r` in a list. iterate the list and replace all such characters and return the modified string.

```
public String replaceMultipleSubstrings(String original, List<String> mylist){
    String tmp = original;
    for(String str: mylist){
        tmp = tmp.replace(str, "");
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Test:

```
mylist.add("\\r");
mylist.add("\\r\\n");
mylist.add("\\n");
mylist.add("\\");  // add back slash

System.out.println("original:" + s);
String x = new Main().replaceMultipleSubstrings(s, mylist);
System.out.println("modified:" + x);
```

Output:

```
original:Kerner\r\n kyky\r hihi\n \"
modified:Kerner kyky hihi "
```

Comment: Thank you its works. Your method deleted all sign what i do not need. I recive 31000entries from DB and it is a little bit slower now, due for-loop what it goes 4 times for each entries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your current replacement logic be correct, but it says now that either `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` gets replaced with empty string, and backslash also gets replaced with empty string.  If so, then you can try the following regex replace all:

```
String s = "Kerner\\r\\n kyky\\r hihi\\n \\\"";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\r|\\n|\\r\\n|\\\\", ""));
```

One problem I saw with your attempt is that you are calling `replace()`, not `replaceAll()`, so it would only do a single replacement and then stop.

Answer (score 0):

`String.replaceAll()` can be used, in your question you tried to use `String.replace()` which does not interpret regular expressions, only plain replacement strings...

You also need to escape the \\ again, i.e. `\\\\` instead of `\\`

```
String s = "Kerner\\r\\n kyky\\r hihi\\n \\\"";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\\\r|\\\\n|\\\\\"", ""));
```

Output

```
Kerner kyky hihi
```

Note the differences between String.replaceAll() and String.replace()

[String.replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given **regular**
>   **expression** with the given replacement.

[String.replace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence))

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified **literal replacement sequence**.

Comment: Not my downvote, but `String#replace()` doesn't need to double escape the backslash, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get this without escaping... Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 12
\r\n|\r|\n|\
            ^

Comment: You don't get it, you're calling `replaceAll()`, the OP is calling `replace()`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I can see that, but he is calling replace() because he believes replace() interprets regex, but it does not...

Comment: Actually I think it does in some cases.  I have countered the downvote on the grounds that your answer may be right, though with a wrong explanation.

Comment: @Adam, I want to delete all \r\n carriage-return from my string. Your code deleted all "\" sign

Comment: @sausagerus Apologies, I misread your question... your original code contains .replace("\\", "") which does the same... it removes the \ characters...Answer updated

Answer (score -1):

Use a regular expression if you want to do all the replaces in one go.
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/search_replace.shtml

Comment: Not helpful. The OP needs a fix, not a reference.

Comment: @nicomp Does OP want me to write the regex for him? I assume he can do so himself.

Comment: You may assume anything but your answer is not an answer.

Comment: @nicomp OP asked how to do all the replaces at once. I gave a way to do so and a link with a tutorial showing exactly how to use that answer....

Comment: @odin A link, though it may be useful, is not an answer.