# How to Insert/Add Backslash Character in a String variable

Tags: character, insertion

I have to get the path of a directory from Java Text field and store it on another string variable but it needs the code of java to add/insert `\` after the colon `:` character.

```
String folderFath="D:\TF";
```

I need to add `\` after the `:` character. I need to get string variable `D:\\TF`

Comment: You can use regex to match the `:` character and add a new \ after that.

Comment: "D:\\TF" will produce the string.

Comment: what type of regex to match : and add \ to the specified string, please help. I also use this code  replaceAll(Pattern.quote("\\"), Matcher.quoteReplacement("\\\\")) . it produce D:     f

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this way "D:\\TF"?

Comment: does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, i need this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answer has exactly what you're looking for. Note that I would have preferred a tag for the language you're using to be sure.

[String.replaceAll single backslashes with double backslashes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1701839/193567)

This code does what I expected it to:

```
  public class JavaFiddle
  {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String myString = "C:\\Text\\Somewhere\\Works"; 
        System.out.println(myString);
        String myStringTwo = myString.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        System.out.println(myStringTwo);
    }
  }
```

Note: What's going on here is the first backslash is an 'Escape Character.' You can't add a backslash directly into a string because it indicates programmatic control.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character

Comment: I have checked it, and produce result is  d:      f

Comment: What language are you programming in? Either one of the two options mentioned will work in Java.

Comment: i am using java Language

Comment: String mystring="D:\TF";    I need to insert only one backslash (\) after  colon (:) to become my desire string is  mystring="D:\\TF"; Note: How it possible?

Comment: Look at the prints. Run the code in a test project. It does what you want.