# Why single blackslash will work too when splitting string with newline

Tags: java, regex

I do understand the concept, where we need 2 backslashes when dealing with regex - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1701876/72437

The following code able to split **hello** and **world** without issue.

```
String message = "hello\nworld";

String[] result = message.split("\\n");

// hello
// world
for (String r : result) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

However, if I use 1 backslash, it works too. (Able to split **hello** and **world** too)

```
String message = "hello\nworld";

String[] result = message.split("\n");

// hello
// world
for (String r : result) {
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

I expect using only 1 backslash for regex will not work in Java. But, it works. May I know why is it so?

Comment: "*I expect using only 1 backslash for regex will not work in Java*" but why? `\n` represents *single* character (at least in bytecode - after compilation), just like `\r`, `\t` or other ones for instance written using `\uXXXX` form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java allows you to specify a newline character in 2 ways.

One is by specifying the character literal `\n`, just as you would split by a comma `,` or any other character that doesn't *need* to be regex-escaped.

But Java [does allow you to specify a special construct for a newline character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

(In the "Summary of regular-expression constructs" section)

> `\n`  The newline (line feed) character (`'\u000A'`)

This is a regular expression construct.  This isn't the single character `\n`, this is a backslash followed by an "n" character, and the backslash would need to be escaped for Java, as you know, as `\\`.

There is nothing forcing you to use the construct `\\n` instead of the literal `\n`.

All this means that you have the option of specifying the character literal `\n` or using the regular expression construct -- 2 characters -- `\\n`.

The construct has the advantage of being printable, in case you would ever want to print the pattern you're splitting by.

```
System.out.println("\\n");  // \n
```

Answer (score 4):

Your single backslash `\n` gets interpreted at compiler level to string as `LINEFEED` character and the `LINEFEED` character is sent into the `String.split()` method, and the java-regex engine got the `LINEFEED` character *directly*.

And in the case of double backslash `\\n` , you have the right understanding. `\\n` in source code gets compiled into `\n` while going into regex-engine; and `\n` is escape code for `LINEFEED` *internally* in java-regex engine

Answer (score 1):

This is an side-effect of how regular expressions are read, why:

```
message.split("\\n");
```

This splits the message on the regex `\` followed by `n`, what gets compiled a [literal newline because of the `\n` escape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

```
message.split("\n");
```

This splits the message on the regex `<newline>` whats also gets compiled to a literal newline

Answer (score 1):

`"\n"` will send as regexp the single character ascii 10.

`"\\n"` will send as regexp the string of length 2: backslash followed by n.

Both does not means the same but produce the same.