# JAVA - How to replace all \ characters to \\ in String

Tags: java

I am trying to replace all `\` characters to `\\` by java. This may be silly question, but I have tried many things for it. My piece of attempt is below :

```
String strToReplace = oldString;

strToReplace = strToReplace.replaceAll("\\","\\\\");
```

The oldString contains "D:\Work\Project\Data". That I read from a property file.
Above is giving me error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\
 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1702)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
```

Any other approach to do this?

Comment: The first line itself doesn't compile!

Comment: Perhaps you need to define `strToReplace` as `"D:\\Work\\Project\\Data";`

Comment: I edited the question. The string contains value that I read from a property file.

Comment: Did you tried `strToReplace.replace("\\","\\\\")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replaceAll` interprets your argument as a RegEx. You need to double escape it.

try following:

```
string.replaceAll("\\\\", "\\\\\\\\");
```

See following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701839/string-replaceall-single-backslashes-with-double-backslashes)